# PHP For loop exiting unexpectedly

Tags: php, sql, for-loop

I am trying to update my table in a database using PHP, I have an array of around 50,000 values each with an update statement in them then I call this code.

```
for($i=0;$i<count($insertData);$i++){
   $result = $conn->query($insertData[$i]);
   if($result){
    echo $insertData[$i] . "\n";
    echo "Update worked!\n";
    }else{
    echo "Update failed\n";
    }
}
```

The length of the array is correct it returns

```
count($insertData);  //Returns ~50,000
```

Then everytime I run the script it only goes up to a random i value (e.g 28 or 32 or 20) and it exits the function. I even do I vardump and all the statements are in there.

```
echo var_dump($insertPlatforms);
```

Looks like... [48391]=>
    "UPDATE table SET field='BLAH' WHERE id = some value

Comment: u need to reset it, or u can use `array_chunks()`

Comment: What do you mean by reset it? Why would I have to use array_chunks() to break it up? It is some special property of PHP? I would assume a for loop is a for loop no matter the language.

Comment: are you sure it isn't crashing on some of the statements? Do you have error reporting turned on?

Comment: Turned on error reporting, it times out after 30 seconds. So that means it is working but the Update statements are taking to long so I am going to try to use array_chunks(). But if the loop stops after i=30, does that mean I have to break up an array of 50,000 indexes with chunks of 30?